# How To use pull in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to delete information from a document but the code runs and no error occurs.But it doesn't delete the record.
I haave data like that

```
{       
  "id": "12345",
   "info": [
    {
        "sno":1
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "xyz@example.com"
    },
    {
        "sno":2
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "xyz@example.com"
    }
  ]      
}
```

and I want to delete data where id=12345 and info.sno=2
my php code id

```
<?
     $m=new Mongo();
     $db=$m->database;
     $cond=array("id"=>'12345');
     $data=array('$pull'=>array("info.sno"=>2));
     //I used before this $data=array('$pull'=>array("info"=>array("sno"=>2)));
     echo json_encode($data);
     $db->info->update($cond,$data);
     $st=$db->Command(array("getlasterror"=>1));
?>
```

I run mongo db command like:

```
    db.info.update({"id":12345},{'$pull':{"info":{"sno":2}}});
```

Comment: quick clarification, the command from the shell is working so you just need to figure out how to write it in PHP, correct?

Comment: Yes Adam C It is correct the only difference is that my id is a string and I used id as an integer also my fiel sno is integer and I used it as a string thats why it didn't work I wrote it like `db.info.update({"id":"12345"},{'$pull':{"info":{"sno":"2"}}});` but the correct way is  `db.info.update({"id":"12345"},{'$pull':{"info":{"sno":2}}});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commented out line is correct:

```
test> db.foo.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f74737cc3a51043d26f4b90"),
    "id" : "12345",
    "info" : [
            {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 2,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            }
    ]
}
test> db.foo.update({"id":"12345"}, {"$pull":{info:{sno:2}}})
test> db.foo.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f74737cc3a51043d26f4b90"),
    "id" : "12345",
    "info" : [
            {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            }
    ]
}
```